# conover test R 4.1.3 packages

Tags: r, package

I recently updated R with R 4.1.3. I used to run conover R with frdAllPairsConoverTest function, using packages PMCMRplus and BWStest. But the package BWStest can't be installed with my version of R. I also tried conover.test seen on R documentation, but the same, I can't install the package.
Do you know a function for conover test that can be run on R 4.1.3 ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information would help answer this, but note that `PMCMRplus` and `BWStest` are packages that rely upon other libraries that require compilation if binaries don't exist for you -- which might be why you've had difficulty installing it. The `conover.test` function seems to be written in "pure" R and therefore should "just work":

`install.packages("conover.test", repos="https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2023-03-01/",source=T)`

works fine for me.